# Deleting values from a variable

Tags: python, pandas

I am a new python learner and have a question about deleting values from variables.

The first 11 data records look like this:

```
Type Latitude Longitude 

Dog     41.9595 82.494997
Cat     41.4388 82.493585
Other   41.5238 82.482829
Bird    41.3848 82.493739
Lizard  41.3838 82.383883
Lizard  41.7238 82.293848
Other   41.7483 82.283848
Other   41.2747 82.474484
Dog     41.3838 82.393949
Cat     41.3883 82.373848
Bird    41.3828 82.383838
```

So, I have imported this to python using

```
import pandas as pd
Pet_Data = pd.read_csv('PetMap.csv',sep=',')
Pet_Data.head()
```

I have made an interactive dot map in bokeh using

```
TOOLTIPS = [("type", "@Type"),       # this accesses 'Type' column
        ("lat", "@Latitude"),    # this accesses 'Latitude' column
        ("lat", "@Longitude")]   # this accesses 'Longitude' column

p = figure(tooltips=TOOLTIPS)        # initiate your figure and add TOOLTIP


p.circle(x='Latitude',               # circles on x
     y='Longitude',                and on y
     source=Pet_Data             # points to Pet_data df
     size=40)                    # simple circle size argument

show(p)
```

So my question is how to delete the ‘other’ data records from the type variable because I don’t want those to show on my map?

Comment: That should be easy to do in pandas.

Comment: `Pet_Data[Pet_Data['type'] != 'Other']`

Comment: try changing `source=Pet_Data` to `source=Pet_Data.query('Type != "Other"')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Pet_Data = pd.read_csv('PetMap.csv',sep=',')
Pet_Data = Pet_Data[Pet_Data['Type']!='Other']
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
Pet_Data = Pet_Data[Pet_Data.Type != 'Other']
```